# swagger, API documentation

Tags: yaml, swagger, documentation

what is wrong with the following YAML syntax.

I have used chatGPT. I have used the swagger editor - Yet, I keep getting errors.

```yaml
/**
 * @swagger
 * /home/{name}:
 *  put:
 *      summary: update a product
 *      tags: [Products]
 *      parameters:
 *          - in: path
 *          name: name
 *          schema:
 *              type: string
 *          required: true
 *          description: The product id
 *      requestBody:
 *          required: true
 *          content:
 *              application/json:
 *                  schema: 
 *                      $ref: "#/components/schemas/Product"
 *      responses:
 *          200: 
 *              description: The product was updated successfully
 *          400:
 *              description: Bad request
 *          500:
 *              description: Internal server error
 *               
 *
 */
```

Comment: check the alignment of the parameters block. `name`, `schema` and other fields needs to be aligned right under `in`

Comment: This is completely invalid OpenAPI syntax. If you ask chatgpt for code you get garbage.